# Get value of string between two tags

Tags: java, regex

I am fairly new regex but I am trying to learn it. I'm not doing anything complicated; I have some XML:

```
<root>
   <friendlyName>Hello, I'm friendly</friendlyName>
   <URL>http://localhost</URL>
</root>
```

I am trying to get the value of friendlyName but it doesn't appear to be working. I've used an online regex tester from `https://regex101.com/` which seems to match against what I'm expecting. However, when I try it in Java I get back `N/A`, `N/A` being what I return if the string was not found.

Below is my code:

```
public String getXMLTagValue(String tagName)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<" + tagName + ">(.*?)</" + tagName + ">/s");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlString);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            return matcher.group();
        }
        return "N/A";
    }
```

I'm expecting the above code to return `Hello, I'm friendly` but instead I get `N/A`.

Comment: Please don't use regular expressions to parse XML. Use an XML parser. It doesn't matter how simple the XML is.

Comment: What is the `/s` meant to be at the end of your `Pattern` string?

Comment: Your XML Is not well formed `<friendlyName>` ends with `</friendly>`

Comment: Important: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Answer (score 0):

You regex is wrongly defined, it must be:

```
"<" + tagName + ">(.*?)</" + tagName + ">\\s"
```

and not

```
"<" + tagName + ">(.*?)</" + tagName + ">/s"
```

Comment: Friendly was a typo it was supposed to be friendlyName on the end as well. I believe /s was to also include line endings which I need

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"<" + tagName + ">(.*?)</" + tagName + ">/s"
```

to

```
"<" + tagName + ">(.*?)</" + tagName + ">\\s"
```

Reason:

> The \s metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character.
>   A whitespace character can be:
>   A space character
>   A tab character
>   A carriage return character
>   A new line character
>   A vertical tab character
>   A form feed character

So the true form is `\s` which when coming to java regex becomes `\\s` (Because `\` is a special character in java)

---

Also I (and some others) think that using `\\s` is not necessary. You can just use this pattern:

```
"<" + tagName + ">(.*?)</" + tagName + ">"
```

Comment: Why should they do that?

Comment: Yes I don't know why he insists on using whitespace pattern. Maybe he wants to read the entire line with `\n`.
Anyway you are right I'm going to update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start correcting your XML  `<friendlyName> ends with </friendly>` , it is not well formed. Then regex is wrong, you can replace:

```
"<" + tagName + ">(.*?)</" + tagName + ">/s"
```

with:

```
"<" + tagName + ">(.*?)</" + tagName + ">\\s"
```

but really you don't need the "\\s".

If you want only the text between the tag you also need to remove the open and close tag before returning the result string.
Below is the working code, I also added an improved method the use the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder to parse the XML instead of regex.

```
private static String xmlString = 
                           "<root>"
                            +"<friendly>Hello, I'm friendly</friendly>"
                            +"<url>http://localhost</url>"
                          +"</root>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String value = getXMLTagValue("friendly");
    System.out.println(value);

    String out = getXMLTagValueImproved("friendly");
    System.out.println(out);

}

public static String getXMLTagValue(String tagName)
{
    String openTag = "<" + tagName + ">";
    String closeTag = "</" + tagName + ">";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(openTag + "(.*?)" + closeTag);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlString);
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        return matcher.group().replaceAll(openTag, "").replace(closeTag, "");
    }
    return "N/A";
}

public static String getXMLTagValueImproved(String tagName) throws Exception {

     InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));  
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder  dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();;
     Document  doc = dBuilder.parse(is);    
     NodeList nl = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    return nl.getLength() > 0 ? nl.item(0).getTextContent() : "N/A" ;
}
```

hope this can help.